# does a popup modal have a web address?

Tags: popup, modal-dialog

Is there a specific address or link that can direct to a specific popup modal? Are all popup modals linked from a page are just contained inside that page, thus, all popup modals linked from that page just have the same web address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends: there are multiple approaches to show modal popup on page like a div with popup content that is hidden and can be shown on a particular event.

Another could be like a standalone web page shown inside a popup modal using iframe, or with Ajax etc..

So if a standalone page is used inside a modal popup it would have a separate url but you can not just put that page's address in browser and get popup because popup is styled using css, you will get to see the page contents.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is what I have been getting from the internet all along. I just needed confirmation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Generally popup modals are present in the same page and are hidden.

But, using jQuery, Angular you can have a address for your modal template and can load the template when modal is required to be displayed.

So, its you choice and requirement.